# Return substrings of a certain length containing the letter k

Tags: php, regex

I have to loop through text files and return substrings found in the text that are either 8 or 9 characters long and contain the letter "k". Some examples of the substrings that must be found: 1998k1748, 1999k426, 2003k3429, 2012k325, etc. What would the regular expression be for this kind of search? I am using PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what I have after using Chirag's expression:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

shell_exec('D:\wamp\bin\xpdf\bin32\pdftotext.exe d.pdf x.txt'); 

$mypdf = file_get_contents("x.txt");

preg_match('\d{4}k\d{3,4}', $mypdf, $result);

echo $result[0];
```

But I get the following error:  Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in D:\wamp\www\pdf2text.php on line 8

Comment: Is required substring only of the form  (4-digit number)k(3-or-4-digit-number)

Comment: @RedBaron: Yes, it is only of the form that you described. Here is a sample of the text that has to be looped through:"verskaf deur die NASIONALE AFRIKAANSE LETTERKUNDIGE MUSEUM en NAVORSINGSENTRUM (NALN) 1998k1748 NASIONALE AFRIKAANSE LETTERKUNDIGE MUSEUM EN NAVORSINGSENTRUM(NALN) Bron: Breytenbach, Breyten Boklied (toneelstuk)"

Comment: Chirag64 has the answer for you then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will work if the string is always in the form of (4-digit-number)k(3-or-4-digit-number) as  described by RedBaron:

```
\d{4}k\d{3,4}
```

Comment: Thanks Chirag, I'll give it a go. I'm quite new to regular expressions. Appreciated.

Comment: I get an error after trying your expression. I have updated my original question with the results.

Comment: Ah, got it! I didn't use delimiters correctly. Thanks, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

How about an if else

```
if ((strlen($string) ==8 || strlen($string) ==9 ) && strpos($string, 'k') ) {
//do somethig
}
```